# mysql: select all rows from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables in mysql dabase with different row numbers and different column, so i want to display all results together

**table_one:**

```
id, name, surname, phone, email
```

**table_two:**

```
id,name,city,phone,website
```

so table_one has 30 rows and table_two has 10 rows
how can i show all together

```
id,name,surname,city,phone,email,website
```

Tried this but is not working

```
SELECT * FROM table_one UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_two ;
```

Comment: How are `table_one` and `table_two` connected with each other?

Comment: is `id` column is the shared key? or `name`?

Comment: `phone` column exists in both tables - which one do you prefer? :-)))

Comment: i dont want to join,  id 1 in table_one and id 1 in table_two, i dont want to be 1 row, they are different rows and need to show both separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have  them on separate rows then this should work:

```
select id,name, '' as surname, city,phone, '' as email, website from table1
union all
select id,name,surname,city,phone,email,website from table2
```

Comment: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: did you try this? you can add a fake column like ` ' 'as email ` so the number of columns match.

Comment: fixed, but how can i search it coz this is not working:
select CLid,name,phone,surname from TABLE_one
        union all
        select CLid,name, phone, 'static_text' as surname from TABLE_two 
           where name LIKE '%BARACK%'

Comment: your query should work but  you need to add the `where` clause to both select statements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply need [`Left join`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp). Left join is used because it seems that you don't have matching rows for all the id(s) in the `table_two`:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name, 
       t1.surname, 
       t2.city, 
       t1.phone, 
       t1.email, 
       t2.website 
FROM table_one AS t1
JOIN table_two AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` should be the best for OP since he mentioned `UNION ALL`

Comment: i dont want to join,  id 1 in table_one and id 1 in table_two are different rows, i dont want to be 1 row, need to show both separately